# want to run two actions when pressing a hotkey

Tags: python, scripting, shortcut

I have these two actions

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT', toggle=False)
bpy.context.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode = (True, False, False) #vertex
```

currently I'm running it from the text editor in blender and it works fine.

I would like to create an addon that could...
run both actions (w the vertex variation) when the Key "1" is pressed,
run both actions (w the edge variation) when the Key "2" is pressed,
run both actions (w the face variation) when the Key "3" is pressed

So far I have this script(addon) working from the text editor, n can be installed n enabled

```
# by EB, done with blender 2.79
bl_info = {
    "name": "EB 3Dview >> EditMode >> VertexSelect",
    "category": "3D View",
}

import bpy


class view3dEditModeVertSel(bpy.types.Operator):
#    """Edit Mode _ Vertex Select"""      # blender will use this as a tooltip for menu items and buttons.
    bl_idname = "view3d.editmode_vertsel"        # only lowercase allowed # unique identifier for buttons and menu items to reference.
    bl_label = "view3dEditModeVertSel"         # display name in the interface.
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}  # enable undo for the operator.

    def execute(self, context):        # execute() is called by blender when running the operator.

        # The original script
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT', toggle=False)
        bpy.context.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode = (True, False, False)

        return {'FINISHED'}            # this lets blender know the operator finished successfully.

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(view3dEditModeVertSel)
    # bpy.ops.view3d.editmode_vertsel()

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(view3dEditModeVertSel)

# This allows you to run the script directly from blenders text editor
# to test the add-on without having to install it.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Hi dr Sybren, ok I got the Addon working w hotkeys and all, I just was wondering, if is it possible to write the "Select Vertex", "Select Edge", n "Select Face" in a single addon, each one with its own hotkey, cuz I have seen that other blender py addons have multiple hotkeys assigned to them, please could you provide a code example for that?

btw would you know what is the difference between these two?

```
km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='Object Mode', space_type='EMPTY')
kmi = km.keymap_items.new(view3dEditModeVertSel.bl_idname, 'SPACE', 'PRESS', ctrl=True, shift=True)
kmi.properties.total = 4
addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))
```

the former is from the Blender Addon Tut, the latter from "PieMenu Addon"

```
km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='Object Non-modal')
kmi = km.keymap_items.new('wm.call_menu_pie', 'Z', 'PRESS')
kmi.properties.name = "pie.shade_of"
addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))
```

thanks advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most future-proof way to go about this is to create your own add-on. First [create an operator](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_master/info_tutorial_addon.html#write-the-add-on-simple) that performs those actions. You can then [bind that operator to the keyboard](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_master/info_tutorial_addon.html#keymap), add it as a button to a panel, add it to a menu, etc.

This is all documented in [Blender's documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_master/info_tutorial_addon.html).

Comment: Hi dr Sybren, please could you provide a code example? I'm new in programming. I had tried reading the blender addon tut before, but I just don't know what class to use for the two actions that I have in my script above. thanks advanced again

Comment: There are code examples in Blender's documentation. Just follow the links and read a little.

Comment: I do have read it, I added the code I'm trying in my question, but it doesn't work, please could you correct it? thx advanced.

Comment: I can fix it, but only if you tell me what's not working, what errors you get, which version of Blender you're using, etc.

Comment: thx dr Sybren, I'm using the last version of blender, I edited my question, added the console error msg, many thanks, I know a bit of python, n AHK, but really blender API is overwhelming

Comment: The bl_idname must be in the form "xxx.yyy", so two components separated by a dot. Also I can recommend following PEP-8 when it comes to naming things and formatting your code.

Comment: Hi, dr Sybren, yes I fix it, I realized the name didn't allowed Uppercase, I edited my question, adding the script(addon) that runs fine in the texte editor, I can install it, enable it, but I just can call it when adding a hotkey, the value that must be place in "None" I don't know what to put there, I tried `bpy.ops.view3d.editmode_vertsel()` but it doesn't work, the console panel says `search for unknown operator` thx advanced

Comment: Hi dr Sybren, ok I got the Addon working w hotkeys and all, I just was wondering, if is it possible to write the "Select Vertex", "Select Edge", n "Select Face" in a single addon, each one with its own hotkey, cuz I have seen that other blender py addons have multiple hotkeys assigned to them, please could you provide a code example for that? thanks advanced.

Comment: To have an operator perform different tasks, you'd have to add a property (probably an [EnumProperty](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_master/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.EnumProperty)) to it, and change the behaviour based on the value of that property. [Blender's documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_master/bpy.props.html#operator-example) already has a code example on this topic too, albeit a rather minimal one. You can use `self.my_float` to access the property value of the example.

Comment: Note: I created [a bug report](https://developer.blender.org/T54286) about this shortcoming in the documentation, which also contains another code example.